# How to display arraylist from sqlite in activity then iterate

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have created an arraylist from my database as below

```
 public List<String> getAllQuestions(){
    List<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();

    String query = "SELECT QUESTION FROM QUESTIONS ";
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query, null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        questions.add(cursor.getString(0));
    }
    cursor.close();


    return questions;

}
```

And basically want to display the first question in the array list, before then clicking my answer and displaying the next question in the array list afterwards... until all questions have been displayed and answered.

My code below however does't work.

```
Button btnAnswer1, btnAnswer2, btnAnswer3;
LoginDataBaseAdapter LoginDataBaseAdapter;
EditText editNameComplete;
int index = 0;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.message);

    LoginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(CompleteSurveyActivity.this);
    LoginDataBaseAdapter.open();



    editNameComplete = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextQuestion);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionnn);

This one works when i only want to get the first without using the array  method.
  //tv.setText(LoginDataBaseAdapter.getQuestion());


however when i try to use the array here, it get a "cannot resolve symbol error.
    tv.setText(LoginDataBaseAdapter.getAllQuestions.get(index));

    //get refs of buttons
    btnAnswer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer1);
    btnAnswer1.setText(LoginDataBaseAdapter.getAnswer1());
    btnAnswer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer2);
    btnAnswer2.setText(LoginDataBaseAdapter.getAnswer2());
    btnAnswer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer3);
    btnAnswer3.setText(LoginDataBaseAdapter.getAnswer3());
}
```

I'm basically just not sure at all how to call and use the getAllQuestions method which creates the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

Import `java.util.ArrayList;` and `java.util.List;` in both classes and it should work. You are using List when you are trying to .get(index); , so you have to import it.